# Why are some questions shown in a different colour?

Tags: support, questions

Following is the image for the same.

[image: Some Questions are normal but some are getting different background colour]

Another favourite tag's list of questions more bright than above:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The yellow background is for questions that belong to your favorite tag(s). Hence the difference in color.

Comment: Two favorite tags but background differs..